# can't access login process function on controller

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have created a simple process_login function in login.php controller.
code:

```
<?php

Class Login extends Controller {

var $title = 'Login';

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('Login_Model');
}

function index() {
    $profile['_profile'] = $this->xProfile_Model->GetProfile();
    $this->load->view('login', array('title' => $this->title, '_profile' => $profile['_profile']));
}

function process_form() {
    $ret['command'] = "login process";
    if($this->input->post('username') == 'admin' && md5($this->input->post('pwd')) == 'e6d8b61d43b5a1c5e4727e92351681f6') {
        //EMERGENCY ONLY
        $data['id'] = '1';
        $data['name'] = 'admin';
        $data['group_id'] = '1';
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        $ret['msg'] = $this->lang->line('msg_success') . ', ' . $this->lang->line('msg_please_wait');
        $ret['status'] = "success";
    }
```

and login view :

```
<form method="post" id="signin" action="<?php echo site_url('login/process_form')?>">
  <label for="username">Username</label>
  <input id="username" name="username" value="" class="required" tabindex="4" type="text" onkeypress="focusNext('pwd', 'login', this, event)" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input id="pwd" name="pwd" value="" class="required" tabindex="5" type="password">
  </p>
  <p class="clear"></p>
  <a href="#" class="forgot" style="display:none;" id="resend_password_link">Lupa password?</a>
  <p class="remember">
    <input id="signin_submit" value="Login" tabindex="6" type="submit"/>
    <input id="cancel_submit" value="Batal" tabindex="7" type="button"/>
    <input id="batal" value="TES" tabindex="7" type="button" onclick="<?php site_url('login/tes')?>"/>

  </p>
</form>
```

When I press login button, then nothing happens there..
What can be wrong with this code?

I was trying form action to:

```
site_url('login/process_form'),site_url('login.php/process_form'),base_url;('process_form')
```

but it's still not working!

Please help me, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't loading a view in your `process_form` function neither are you doing a redirect to a page that will actually load content.

also, the way its written right now if the conditions of your if statement aren't met it shouldn't do anything, and actually the function isn't closed.

lastly, there are errors in the html

1. there isn't an html input type of button, its proper syntax would be

   `<button id="batal" tabindex="7">TES</button>`

also, the onclick isn't right which may be why your form isn't submitting.  right now it would just render as `onclick="someurl..."` you need to make it submit your form.